# No internet connection with bridge adapter

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I had internet connection inside my virtual box but after not using it for over a week I am not having internet connection. (Similar [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/722512/virtualbox-ubuntu-14-04-bridge-adapter-not-working) to the question posted on ask ubuntu)

The things that come to my mind are:

1. Reset router
2. Enabled serial port between my 2 virtual machines

I've followed the steps suggested by other answers in stack-exchange and none did work. (when I switch to NAT I have internet connection but for debugging purposes I must have it as `bridge-adapter` for having different ips for each VM

Host Machines: Win10
Here are the settings of the VM: (vm are running linux 4.17.0v kernel)

[image]

```
ifconfig
```

---

```
eth0    Link encap: Ethernet HWaddr 08:00:27:dd:5d:7f
        inet6 addr: fe80:a00:27ff:fedd:5d7f/64 Scope:Link
        UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
        RX packets:14 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:29 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
        RX bytes:3847 (3.8 KB) TX bytes:4962 (4.9 KB)

lo      Link encap:Local Loopback
        inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mast:255.0.0.0
        inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
        UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric:1
        RX packets:151 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:151 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
        RX bytes:10965 (10.9 KB) TX bytes:10965 (10.9 KB)
```

---

```
ipconfig (in host)
```

---

```
Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 1:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 11:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::18dd:2b82:c82:2f51%19
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.21
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

Comment: Since it's set to bridged connection, are the host and guest set to the same subnet? Is the guest picking up an IP through DHCP or did you set an IP address statically? It would help if you could edit your post to include the relevant info from ipconfig/ifconfig on the host and guest.

Comment: Which version of VirtualBox do you use? Does your vm get IP from the router if you use Bridged mode? Do you see the VM's DHCP activity in your router's log? Could you set manually the IP, routing and name resolution on the VM?

Comment: @n8te added the information.

Comment: @Tony you have three wifi adapters. Two of them are only logical interfaces? If not, are you sure the virtual adapter is connected to the active wifi?

Comment: @deadcandidate not sure what you mean by "virtual adapter is connected to the active wifi" But I have switched between all the Adapter1-4 in the Network settings and started the VM each time with one of them and there was no connection.

Comment: @Tony as far as I can remember, on Windows, you can connect guest's network adapters to any interfaces known by Windows host. But another idea: some month ago, there was a bug in Virtualbox 5.2.x which caused same problem. You can find details on google, if you search for expression "qualcomm wifi virtualbox". If it doesn't help, have you tried to use static IP in the guest?